# trying to set focus of dynamically added input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bear of a time getting this input to focus.  It is dynamically loaded.  On the blur of the input, it is supposed to do some checking and then go back to that input if incorrect id entered.  $(itemID) is what I am trying to focus.

Here is my javascript function that is called on page load.

```
function addBlurEvent() {
            $("#brochureItems").on("blur", ".item-ID", (function (e) {
                var itemID = $(this);
                var itemIDVal = $.trim($(this).val());               

                if (itemIDVal != "") {
                    var item = "";
                    $.each(window.listOfItems, function(i, v) {
                        if (v.No.search(itemIDVal) != -1) {
                            item = v.Description;
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    if(item != "") {
                        $(itemID).parent().parent().siblings(".item-desc").find("input").first().val(item);
                        $(itemID).parent().siblings(":last").find("input").first().focus();
                    } else {
                        slideDownMsg("Item: " + itemIDVal + " not found.");
                        slideUpMsg(3000);
                        $(itemID).focus();
                    }

                } else {
                    $(itemID).parent().siblings(".item-desc").find("input").first().val("");
                    $(itemID).parent().siblings(":last").find("input").val("")
                }
            }));
            $(".removeRow").on('click', function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            });
        }
```

And here is the dynamically added table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="brochureItems">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Item Code
        </th>
        <th>
            Brochure Code
        </th>
        <th width="35%">
            Item Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Retail
        </th>
        <th>
            Remove
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="brochureItems_0__itemNo" class="form-control text-box single-line valid item-ID" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Item Code field is required." name="brochureItems[0].itemNo" aria-invalid="false" type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="brochureItems_0__brocCode" class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Brochure Code field is required." name="brochureItems[0].brocCode" type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="row item-desc">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="brochureItems_0__itemDesc" class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Item Description field is required." name="brochureItems[0].itemDesc" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" onfocus="this.blur()" type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="brochureItems_0__retail" class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Retail must be a number." data-val-required="The Retail field is required." name="brochureItems[0].retail" type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove removeRow"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I can only see that in the inspector.  Source code shows an empty div where the table is supposed to go.

I don't think it matters, but that addBlurEvent function is getting called in the success of an ajax call.  Here is the first function that gets called:

```
function loadItems() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("_BrochureItems", "Brochure")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { model: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.brochureItems)) },
                success: function (results) {
                    $("#itemList").html(results);
                    addBlurEvent();
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    displayError("Error", request.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Events are only added to currently existing elements in the DOM. You need to apply the event to each input that is dynamically created after initial page load.

Comment: but this function is called on page load after the items are dynamically added

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question? Note `itemID` is defined as a jQuery object at `var itemID = $(this)`, calling `jQuery()` again with `itemID` as parameter is not necessary.

Comment: So, one thing: You're wrapping a jQuery object in a jQuery object, which is a bit odd. `itemID` is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to do `$(itemID).focus()`, you can just do `itemID.focus()`. It's not a big deal to do so, just looks funny. The code you have should work, unless the element does not exist or is disabled. Check your console for any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I changed the references to `itemID` now.  No errors except a missing woff2 file which never seems to go away or affect anything important.

Comment: No element at `html` has `id` `"brochureItems"` or `className` `"item-ID"`?

Comment: Make sure your jQuery is using DOM methods when creating and appending HTML Controls, input elements are not plain HTML.

Comment: @guest271314: yes i am

Comment: @BekimBacaj: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @dmikester1  The referenced elements do not appear at `html` at Question?

Comment: Sorry, copied my HTML incorrectly, it is there now.

Comment: @dmikester1 It's a mistake people make frequently, using DHTML methods for creating and accessing HTML controls on the fly by stream injection. But it doesn't always work as expected as they sometimes fail to fully initialize. Need to use DOM Element creation, such as document.createElement instead (to make sure). So I was just pointing it out.

Comment: Where are `slideDownMsg` and `slideUpMsg` defined?

Comment: Those are in a seperate js file, I even tried commenting those 2 lines out and it didn't change anything.

Comment: What is purpose of `onfocus="this.blur()"`?

Comment: @guest271314: it is so the readonly inputs cannot get focus.  Normally when you click on them, it puts the cursor in the input box.

Comment: @dmikester1 `input` having `readonly` attribute should not gain focus or get a cursor within the field when clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  I figured there must be a way because my other events in that function were working, just not that focus event.  Ended up finding this SO Q&A which solved my issue: [jquery focus back to the same input field on error not working on all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071752/jquery-focus-back-to-the-same-input-field-on-error-not-working-on-all-browsers)

Essentially, I had to set a timeout on the focus.  So here is the code to do that:

```
setTimeout(function() { itemID.focus(); }, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `()` around your function.

Issues with the `siblings`  I made assumptions

Some code is useless and I commented it out.
Some code is "not present" in your example so I commented out references to that.

I made some assumptions that you wanted to focus the "cell" in the same TD row referenced by the "td" with a `.row` class.

```
function addBlurEvent() {
  $("#brochureItems").on("blur", ".item-ID", function(e) {
    var itemID = $(this);
    var itemIDVal = $.trim(itemID.val());

    if (itemIDVal != "") {
      var item = "";
      /* $.each(window.listOfItems, function(i, v) {
         if (v.No.search(itemIDVal) != -1) {
           item = v.Description;
           return;
         }
       });
       */
      if (item != "") {
        // only one input in a cell (td)
        // itemID.parent('.row').siblings(".item-desc").find("input").first().val(item);
        itemID.parent('.row').siblings(".item-desc").find("input").val(item);
        // no siblings of the inputs parent div exist in the TD cell
        itemID.parent('.row').siblings(":last").find("input").first().focus();
      } else {
        //slideDownMsg("Item: " + itemIDVal + " not found.");
        //slideUpMsg(3000);
        itemID.focus();
      }

    } else {
      itemID.parent('.row').siblings(".item-desc").find("input").val("");
      itemID.parent('.row').siblings().last().find("input").val("")
    }
  });
  $(".removeRow").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
}
```

Reference fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xL8wh3qo/

See this updated fiddle where I show examples of how to save a table row, clone it and then allow you to add new rows to your table from that. Even if all the rows are removed, you can add a new one from the saved clone, with proper id's based on your original row:  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27778/

Comment: Remove the () around what function? The fiddle does not focus on `.item-ID` on blur either.

Comment: I'm not having any problems with adding or removing rows.  Did you read my question?

Comment: Yes, did you review the actual focus code, basically your selectors are/were not for the elements.  Note also that you CAN put the event handler hooks on the element you insert the table into to avoid doing it when you get the data; as in the example I linked to.   I only included the second example to illustrate how to do that.

Comment: Note in regards to the first question `$("#brochureItems").on("blur", ".item-ID", (function (e) {` see that `(` just before the function?

Comment: Note also that the "insert row" was also to demonstrate the event handler is hooked outside the rows and thus new rows (IF you insert this way) would inherit the event handlers without need to re-attach to new elements i.e. new rows.

Comment: Aw, I apologize for my comment then.