# Can't focus back to input field after blur

Tags: javascript, input, focus, alert, blur

So I have look at most related link on my problem and can't seems to make it work.

Tried the workaround on this link [jquery focus back to the same input field on error not working on all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071752/jquery-focus-back-to-the-same-input-field-on-error-not-working-on-all-browsers) but it didn't work for me.

I have a javascript that evaluate the value of an input field on exit (blur).  That works well.  The problem is when the value is wrong, I show an alert, delete the content of the field and set the focus back on the faulty field.

There comes the problem. In Firefox, the focus will still go on the other field which I clicked on (triggering the blur() of the previous field).
In IE(11.0.9600) or Chrome(64.0), the alert shows but keeps coming back in  some sort of infinite loop.  I have to kill the browser.

So here is a VERY truncated version of my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="OUTPUT WEB CHANNEL_WEB simplex" section="ChargesLinesList" dpi="96" scale="1.0">
<input id="dateBilled" class="myDateField" name="dateBilled" value="2018-01-18" type="text">
<input id="dateBilled" class="myDateField" name="dateBilled" type="text">
<input id="dateBilled" class="myDateField" name="dateBilled" type="text">
```

and this is my code to validate the value and show the alert:

```
$(".myDateField").on("blur", function(event){
    var myDateFormat = /^(((((1[26]|2[048])00)|[12]\d([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48]))-((((0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)))|(02-(0[1-9]|[12]\d))))|((([12]\d([02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789]))|((1[1345789]|2[1235679])00))-((((0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)))|(02-(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))))$/;
    if(!myDateFormat.test($(this).val())){
      alert('Invalid date or format.  Make sure you the format his YYYY-MM-DD and the date is valid');
      $(this).val("");
      $(this).focus();
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code? The code you posted applies the blur listener to all three `<input>`s, which I guess is what makes the browser hang. This `setTimeout(() => { this.focus(); }, 50);` works for me.

Comment: this will cause a never ending alert loop

Comment: You're creating a potential infinite loop because every time the focus changes, the previous field is going to get a `blur` event, and if it fails validation then you'll try to `focus` it, causing the other field to get `blur`, but if it's invalid it'll try to `focus`, and so on.

Comment: Also note that one can still press tab to circumvent this (as demonstrated by the answer below). I consider this bad UX and would rather put a red border around the field or something and disable the submit button. Let people fill out the form in the order they want.

Comment: @ChrisG Pressing `TAB` will not circumvent the `change` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `blur` event triggers whenever a field loses the focus, but in your case, when someone leaves a field and clicks into another one, `blur` will fire for the first field, and if that field fails your validation, the focus will switch back to it, causing the other field that the user clicked into to lose the focus and then `blur` will fire for that field and so on.

Instead, you should be using the `change` event, which triggers when the focus is lost, but ***only if the value of the field has changed*** since it got the focus. This will avoid an infinite loop and `.focus()` will then work properly.

Also, you can't have multiple elements with the same `id` and each text box should also have a unique name.

Lastly, your `<html>` tag is full of attributes that are not valid for HTML. Most of what you are doing there should be accomplished via media queries.

```js
$(".myDateField").on("change", function(event){
    var myDateFormat = /^(((((1[26]|2[048])00)|[12]\d([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48]))-((((0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)))|(02-(0[1-9]|[12]\d))))|((([12]\d([02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789]))|((1[1345789]|2[1235679])00))-((((0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)))|(02-(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))))$/;
    if(!myDateFormat.test($(this).val())){
      alert('Invalid date or format.  Make sure you the format his YYYY-MM-DD and the date is valid');
      $(this).val("");
      $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="dateBilled1" class="myDateField" name="dateBilled1" value="2018-01-18" type="text">
<input id="dateBilled2" class="myDateField" name="dateBilled2" type="text">
<input id="dateBilled3" class="myDateField" name="dateBilled3" type="text">
```